# When I try to load PerchCMS (or any page) on 127.0.0.1:8080, browser times out

Tags: php, mysql, macos, localhost, perch

Last night I set up a PHP server on my Mac and installed Perch CMS. I used this command in terminal to do so: php -S 127.0.0.1:8080 and Terminal responded with "listening on http://127.0.0.1:8080" and stated the correct document root.

It was working great for hours.

Turned off the server, went to sleep. This morning I turned it back on and...nothing works. When I try to load 127.0.0.1:8080/industry-template/index.php, nothing loads and the browser eventually times out.

I have tried restarting the server, restarting the browser, restarting my computer, changing the document root, restarting MySQL, loading different pages, loading html pages....

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bit late for the OP but in case anyone else finds this post and is having issues setting up a local Perch CMS environment.

In general, I would recommend using Docker to set up your local development environment for Perch CMS. The linked Docker Compose project will install and configure all the dependencies required to run Perch CMS on your laptop.

https://github.com/lbrack1/perch-docker-compose